# Как обнаружить место скопление данных и освободить память после скрипта?

Tags: javascript

После сборки GIF при помощи [yahoo/gifshot](https://github.com/yahoo/gifshot) Google Chrome показывает **js heap** в **190мб** и это значение иногда остается даже после завершения всей сборки. Что характерно пока вкладка не перезагружена, так и стоит около **190мб** периодически на +-5мб меняя значение.

Как можно вычислить где место, которое скапливает данные и не очищается. Пробовал делать снимок **Heap snapshot**, только не понял как там что понять, а точнее что занимает столько места в памяти. Например в самом верху с сортировкой по убыванию, находились куча элементов с названием **(object elements)[]@420433** и как понять что это значит и где этот элемент в коде?!

Кто знает метод обнаружить место сбора большого кол-ва данных с возможностью указание объекта в коде, чтобы понять где вообще этот объект\массивы или функция?

Comment: начать можно отсюда: [Fix Memory Problems](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems)

Comment: @Grundy статья устарела видимо, таких вкладок и инструментов уже нет в хроме. Это видимо очень старая версия хрома. Да и тут так же не понятно что делать с этой информацией, так как у найденных объектов нет ни каких указателей или ссылок в снапшоте, чтобы идентифицировать их в коде.

Comment: Да, некоторые инструменты переместились: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference